# Javascript Подгрузка скрипта

Tags: javascript

Я делаю [игру](http://www.newgrounds.com/projects/games/998044/preview) и у меня проблема с её загрузкой.Если обновить страницу пару раз то всё подгружается,но без этого,как я не пытался сделать,ничего не работает.Если нужен javascript код то я добавлю,там просто много.

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    overflow: auto;
 background: url("image/bg.png") repeat;
}
p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 50;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="Utf-8">
  <title>
   Sietra
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas width="960" height="576" id="canvas" style="z-index: 0;"><p>Ваша версия браузера не поддерживает Canvas.<br>Обновите браузер!</p></canvas>
  <script src="image.js"></script>
  <script src="variable.js"></script>
  <script src="engine.js"></script>
  <script src="character.js"></script>
  <script src="enemy.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: если не загружались скрипты, зачем нам нужен ваш html код? Вопрос не корректен, скажите какие технологии вы используете при построении приложения, какие ошибки вылетают

Comment: Посмотрите, какой вывод в консоли в момент, когда возникает проблема. Если там вылезают какие-то ошибки, то нужно разбираться в зависимости от их текста.

Comment: Скрипты загружаются,ошибок нет.Но он не загружается при первом запуске,если обновить страницу,всё в порядке.

Comment: Подчинил всё создав кнопку которая подгружает страницу если она не загрузилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подчинил всё создав кнопку которая подгружает страницу если она не загрузилась.